# XCode 4 repository remotely?

Tags: xcode, macos

xcode 4 creates repository automatically.where can I know the path? can i set remote
repository in server from xcode 4?  can I configure it without any specail svn softwares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the path by going to Organizer--> repository

and xCode 4 give you 2 SVN ways, Git and Subversion

read this article to understands the differences and how to use them

[Repositories, Snapshots, and Archives](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/SCM/SCM.html)

Comment: you did not say how to configure remote repository without any software, through xcode only?

Comment: let's said that you have another one want to work with you on the project, you will create the project, and make your mac as a server to let the other one access your mac, and the other one have to go to the xcode welcome screen and choose "connect to repository" it will ask him about the location, and the location will be your project in your mac, you have to grant him a permission to access your mac.

Comment: i didn't try it, maybe i'm mistaken my friend.

Comment: you are partially right my friend.what i am asking, my alteration in code , and also my friend's alteration in code will be committed in remote server not in my mac.is it possible without using any paid software like svn?

Comment: you don't have to use any software, 
read this article 
[link]http://www.covertapps.com/development/6-setting-up-your-xcode-scm-repositories[/link]

Comment: forgive me my friend,
this is the link
[link](http://www.covertapps.com/development/6-setting-up-your-xcode-scm-repositories)